# Multivariable Calculus Course Extra Credit Challenge

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am allowed to consult other resources/individuals as long as I mention your name/position on the problem sheet. I have no idea how to even begin. This is well beyond the scope of my course. My instructor wants his students to interact/discuss this with the mathematics community.

Here it is:

Let Ω be a convex region in R2 and let L be a line segment of length ι that connects points on the boundary of Ω. As we move one end of L around the boundary, the other end will also move about this boundary, and the midpoint of L will trace out a curve within Ω that bounds a (smaller) region Γ. Find an expression that relates the area of Γ to the area of Ω in terms of the length ι.

Comment: there are a couple of papers on this will try to dig up references ... the first of these may have been from around 1850's

Answer (score 3):

The relevant result is known as [Holditch theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holditch%27s_theorem) . From Wikipedia:
Holditch's theorem states that if a chord of fixed length is allowed to rotate inside a convex closed curve, then the locus of a point on the chord a distance $p$ from one end and a distance $q$ from the other is a closed curve whose area is less than that of the original curve by $\pi pq$.

His paper is
Rev. Hamnet Holditch, "Geometrical theorem"
[The Quarterly Journal of Pure and Applied Mathematics 2, 1858, p. 38.](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN600494829_0002&DMDID=DMDLOG_0007)
His one-page proof is beatiful.

I more modern (and more analytic) exposition is
Arne Broman, "A fresh look at a long-forgotten theorem",
[Mathematics Magazine 54(3), May 1981, 99–108.](http://www.math.pitt.edu/~troy/sflood/holditch.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest working it out for some simple $\Omega$.

If $\Omega$ is a circle of radius $R$, then $\Gamma$ is again a circle with radius $r<R$ that can be easily computed.

If $\Omega$ is a rectangle, then $\Gamma$ is the same rectangle with a quarter of circle taken out in each corner, see he picture below. Again computations can be made exactly.

[image]

In both cases
$$
\text{area}(\Gamma)=\text{area}(\Omega)-\frac{\pi}{4}\,l^2.
$$
That is, the area of $\Gamma$ is the area of $\Omega$ minus the area of a circle of radius $l/2$. Knowing the answer may show the way to the proof.